# Select first 5 values of a column after applying a filter, without duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I applied autofilter to the column. That part of the code is running properly, but on that condition there are supposed to be 20 values in that column but I want only five.

```vb
    Dim rFirstFilteredRow As Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$6").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="1"
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Rows.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    Set rFirstFilteredRow = _
                      .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Columns(2).Cells
                    rFirstFilteredRow.Copy
                    Range("G16").Select
                    ActiveSheet.Paste
                    
                End If
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

This gets the first column after filter but not the first five.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `.Resize(5)` when setting the width of `rFirstFilteredRow` to resize the selection to 5 rows high.

Example below (I shortened the code a lot):

```
Sub Answer()
Dim rFirstFilteredRow As Range

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$6").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="1"

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Rows.Count).Offset(1, 0)
        If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
            ' Select first 5 columns starting at column 2
            Set rFirstFilteredRow = _
              .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Columns(2).Resize(5)
            rFirstFilteredRow.Copy
            Range("G16").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You're right, edited to fix, sorry I missed that

Comment: its still selecting rows instead of columns

Comment: Sorry I set it to select the first 5 columns, when what you want is for it to select the first five rows within the first column. Fixed again.

Comment: Glad to hear - please mark it as an accepted answer so the question shows as answered to other SO users.

Comment: getting run time error 1004 while working on dynamic range on this line With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Rows.Count).Offset(1, 0)

Comment: can u please add a code where it works for dynamic range too?ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$6").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="1" editing this line isnt working

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by a dynamic range. If you want the autofilter and the rest of it to apply to the same range, I recommend setting that range as a separate range variable at the start of the code. `Range("$A$1:$D$6")` and `.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion` are both Ranges, and `.Autofilter` and `.Resize` are range methods that could be applied to any range.

Comment: can u please write the code if i want to select till D50 ,i have tried every combination,it is still selecting cells till D6,please rewrite code once with higher range

Comment: @shalini You can't resize the non-contiguous range that `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` returns. It just uses the first cell in the range and resizes that. So if the visible range is `A$21:$AC$22,$A$27:$AC$29` the resized range in columns 2 would be `$B$21:$B$25`

Comment: @Shalini step through the code line-by-line using F8, and see which line in the code isn't doing what you think it is. Possibly material for another question.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Sub macro2()

    Const MAXROWS = 5
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Dim i As Long, c As Range
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Range("$A$1:$D$6").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="1"
    With ws.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Columns(2)
        Set rng = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With
    i = 0
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If i > 0 Then ' skip header
           ws.Range("G16").Offset(i - 1) = c.Value2
        End If
        i = i + 1
        If i > MAXROWS Then Exit For
    Next

End Sub
```